# trying to parse a too large object in java to json

Tags: java, json, file, memory

I have a big object in java I want to save in a file as a JSON.

```
private String serializeToJson(T item) {
    String json;
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    try {
        json = ow.writeValueAsString(item);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        json = "";
    }
    return json;
}
```

this is my code and I get a memory error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:201)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.util.TextBuffer.contentsAsString(TextBuffer.java:362)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.io.SegmentedStringWriter.getAndClear(SegmentedStringWriter.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:394)
    at com.waze.routing.automation.io.string.JsonFileHandler.serializeToJson(JsonFileHandler.java:81)
    at com.waze.routing.automation.io.string.JsonFileHandler.save(JsonFileHandler.java:44)
    at com.waze.routing.automation.io.string.JsonFileHandler.saveBaseLine(JsonFileHandler.java:35)
```

what ways can I use to save large objects as JSON in a file?

I don't want to add complexity of DB at the moment.

I have thought to ignore some fields in the parsing, using `@JsonIgnore`

but is there any way of other parsing framework that can solve this?

Comment: looks similar this  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553285/best-way-of-writing-big-json-files-avoiding-outofmemory-issues)

Comment: Have you looked at streaming it using something like `com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter`?

Comment: @RobertBain how can I investigate it? how do you suggest